# Can provide an open file description/socket ID directly to a subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I'd like for Python to open a socket, but to provide that socket to a subprocess to read.
For boring reasons, I'd prefer it if Python never had to read from the socket after opening the connection.

For example --- is it possible to do something like this:

```
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
      # Just guessing here
    os.openSubProcess("myprocess", stdin=s.kernalSocketID)
    ...
```

I only care about Unix-land here.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just pass the info to open the socket to the subprocess?

Comment: Sure -- one reason is that its a lot of data (gigabytes) and the destination program is C program that is GPU optimized for decoding the stream, and it accepts stdin as a source.
Another reason is -- the python process is a server, and has to go back to doing other things. Having Python (async single-threaded/GIL locked) pushing bytes around seems like bad design.

Comment: `os.sendfile` or `os.splice`?

Comment: os,splice looks like the thing. Thanks.